# remove all characters after a character using regular expression in php

Tags: php, regex

I need to remove all the characters after the character which I select in a string. 
Here is my string

```
$string = "Blow the fun in the sun.paste a random text";
        $new_string = preg_replace("/paste.*/","",$string,-1,$count);
        echo $new_string;
```

My output is `Blow the fun in the sun.`

If my string is like this

```
$string = "Blow the fun in the sun.paste \n a random text";
        $new_string = preg_replace("/paste.*/","",$string,-1,$count);
        echo $new_string;
```

My output is

```
Blow the fun in the sun.
a random text
```

But, I need my output as `Blow the fun in the sun.` even if there are `\n or \t or some other special characters` in my strings. How can I match this, while taking those special characters into consideration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need `s` flag (DOTALL) to make DOT match new lines:

```
$new_string = preg_replace("/paste.*/"s, "", $string, -1, $count);
```

Without `s` flag your regex is not matching new lines as your input contains new lines and you want to replace string that contains new line as well.

Comment: `s,"/paste.*/"s,"/paste.*/s",`

Comment: @anubhava you have lots of anubhav

Comment: However you didn't really need last 2 arguments in `preg_replace`.